# remove element from list while overload function with Frida

Tags: javascript, java, android, overloading, frida

I debug an android application with Frida and I overload function that return `java.util.List<SomeObject>`

I want to remove the first element from List that the function is return.

How can I do that please?

```
Java.perform(function x() {
    
    var my_class = Java.use("a.b");
    my_class.c.overload().implementation = function () { 
        var s= this.c(); // THE FUNCTION RETURN java.util.List<SomeObject>
        //HERE I WANT TO REMOVE THE FIRST ELEMENT IN S
        return s;
        
    };
});
```

Here is `c` function:

```
public List<SomeObject> c() {
        return this.c;
    }
```

Comment: @Robert I update the post with `c` function , so should I run `Java.cast(s, Java.use("java.util.List")).remove(0);` ?

Comment: The code still does not show if the List is mutable or not as it simply returns the field value `this.c`. Check where the `c` field is written.

Comment: @Robert it's write like `this.c = Util.immutableList(......)`

Comment: Then you have your answer, a mutable list is very unlikely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to cast the variable `s` to `java.util.List`, then you can call methods on it or use it as argument, e.g. to create a new List.

The following code works if the List `c()` returns is mutable:

```
let s = this.c(); 
let list = Java.cast(s, Java.use("java.util.List"));
list.remove(0);
return list;
```

If the returned List is immutable you need to create a new mutable array and the delete then first element:

```
let s = this.c(); 
let list = Java.cast(s, Java.use("java.util.List"));
let newList = Java.use("java.util.ArrayList").$new(list);
newList.remove(0);
return newList;
```

Mutable Lists are e.g. `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`. Immutable are e.g. created by `List.of(...)` `Arrays.asList(...)`, by wraping a list with `Collections.unmodifiableList()` or usually by stream/lambda expressions.